# iOS 8 using story builder to design for iPhone in portrait mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, autolayout

I am using **Xcode 6.1.1** and **iOS 8** and story builder to design my app to work for both **iPhone 4** and **iPhone 6** but I am having **troubles in understanding the auto layout.**

---

These are the **steps** I took:

- I selected iPhone and **portrait mode** only in the project settings
- In story builder I have added some elements to it and chosen the option **compact:w regular:h** which should be for all iPhone in portrait mode.
- I have added several elements and **they all seem to fit the view** in storybuilder
- I have added the suggested missing constraints

---

**Result** I get:

- I got an iPad only at the moment I run it there but once I do so the layout gets messed up and some element disappear

---

**Questions** I have:

- **Why is this happening?** The iPad is an iPad Air (model: ME407B/A)
- Is adding the suggested constraints enough?
- Are there any other steps I should take? Or a good tutorial to follow?

Comment: "These are the steps I took" But I notice that none of those steps is "learn auto layout". Learn it. Using it without understanding what you're doing is just silly.

Comment: This is a good tutorial. http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus/

Comment: "I have added the suggested missing constraints." Using "suggested constraints" has a worse than 50-50 chance of giving you the constraints you actually want.